# Get mac address from gateway

Tags: macos, terminal, ip

I want to be able to get the mac address from the gateway with a bash script.

My idea was to get the gateway IP:

netstat -nr | grep default

However I get this:

default            192.168.1.1        UGSc           77        0     en0

I would somehow need to get rid of everything on the line and make it just read the IP so then I could then do the following command:

arp -n -i en0 $ip

If anyone could help me or think of a better way of doing it that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
netstat -nr | grep default | awk '{print $1}'
```

If you do lots of bash scripting, you should probably get familiar with [awk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), which does this type of things (and is pretty mighty by the way).

Answer (score 1):

Another answer that works on Mac OS X is:

```
route get default | grep '^    gateway:' | cut -f 6 -d " " | xargs arp | cut -f 4 -d " "
```